# syntax error 'EOL while scanning string literal (<unknown>, line 9)'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import os

async def cmdrun(client, message, prefix):
    cmd = message.content.split(' ')[0].split(prefix)[1]
    args = message.content.split(cmd)[1][1:].split(' ')
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            imported = filename.split('.py')[0]
            strin = f"from commands.{imported} import name, aliases, run\nx = name()\ny = aliases()\nawait message.channel.send(x + y)\nif x == {cmd} or {cmd} in y:\n    await run(client, message, args)"
            exec(strin)
```

I am making a discord bot with discord.py.
What is the error

Comment: It is python 3.8.1

Comment: It seems to be complaining about the EOL (\n) characters embedded in your string.

Comment: Then How do I end a line

Comment: You should really think about your software design. I don't know your use-case but creating some python code on the fly and then executing it via `exec` is in 99,99% not the right way. Set `imported` and `cmd` to a valid string value, then your example works, so some of your parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

That error is definitely always associated with a missing double-inverted/single-inverted comma. Here's my suggestions:

1. Try running the prepared lines of code you're attempting to use as is.
2. I couldn't find anything in the [new documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), but the [old
   documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) suggest that `...in the current implementation, multi-line compound statements must end with a newline: exec "for v in seq:\n\tprint v\n" works, but exec "for v in seq:\n\tprint v" fails with SyntaxError`. Perhaps try adding a new line character at the end?
3. Try using triple inverted commas.

Hope this solves the issue!

Comment: Ah, sorry mate. I am not very familiar with the intricacies of the exec function, only used it a couple of times. Hope you get the solution soon.